Accessing local network drive on Docker
Pardon for the wall of text but it's a mildly complex issue: I'm trying to perform a YOLO multi machine training with DistributedDataParallel. Since the company I work at uses Windows machines, I'm using Docker containers, one in each machine, to perform such training with more stability. Currently we've faced a problem though:
Machine 1, the one from which I'm typing this, has a connected hard disk to it, where the dataset is located. Machine 2 has access this drive through the local network (Windows).
Things I tried:
1: running both containers with this command, both containers have identical images btw:

[Command 1]: docker run -v F:\Dataset:/workspace/datasets --rm -it --gpus all -p : yolo_master

The path F:\Dataset is the same in both computers btw. Machine 1 works fine, but machine 2 shows the /workspace/datasets folder as empty inside the container. The machines are definitely capable of communicating btw as when I try the Pytorch command for multiple machines training one machine reacts reactively to the other as expected, of course the lack of a dataset folder in the second container causes an error.
2: attempting to create a Docker volume on both machines.
Based on this article: Mounting a Windows Shared Folder to a Docker container | by Wynne Lo | Medium I have tried to run this command:

[Command 2]: docker volume create --driver local --opt type=cifs --opt device=///F/dataset --opt o=username=[username redacted],password=[password redacted],domain=[computer name, redacted],vers=1.0 matvervolume

It creates the volume in both machines, I can run the container using [Command 1] on machine 1, but on machine 2 I have this issue:

docker: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/matvervolume/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount //[redacted]/F/Dataset:/var/lib/docker/volumes/matvervolume/_data, data: username=[redacted],password=********,domain=[redacted],vers=1.0: host is down.

On Windows (machine 2):

net use Z: \\F\Dataset /user:[redacted] [redacted password] *


ping [redacted-IPv4]

Both work perfectly and return the expected results. Which leads me to believe it's a matter of Docker or WSL2 being unable to connect to the other machine, but I'm a loss on how to make this communication happen at this point.
